# Application Error: Could not load file or assembly file:///D:\CISPL\APP\DocProDms\bin\GroupDocs.Viewer.dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish, fusion-log-viewer

first of all I don't know if this question can be asked on stackoverflow or not and secondly I know the log file below is very big, but I wanted everyone to understand the error properly, and please don't close this question as I already tried fusionlog(some times my question get closed and they share the reference which is already tried by my).

We have a product(asp.net mvc application) which is deployed on multiple clients, but on one of my client machine when I uploaded the application on IIS and run the application I got the following error ->

> Application Error: Could not load file or assembly
> 'file:///D:\CISPL\APP\DocProDms\bin\GroupDocs.Viewer.dll' or one of
> its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80131515)

I used fusionlog to check the error.

and the below is my fusionlog.

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2022/08/08 @ 15:49:18) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = GroupDocs.Viewer, Version=19.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=716fcc553a201e56
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/CISPL/APP/DocProDms/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\CISPL\APP\DocProDms\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\docprodmsuat\c5cf6538
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\docprodmsuat\c5cf6538
LOG: AppName = 51d8e465
Calling assembly : DocPro.DMS.WebApp, Version=2022.6.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b47288d74d395c83.
===
WRN: No matching native image found.
LOG: IL assembly loaded from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\docprodmsuat\c5cf6538\51d8e465\assembly\dl3\6b54b840\c6de7e7b_bd8cd801\GroupDocs.Viewer.dll.

*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (2022/08/08 @ 15:49:18) ***

The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = GroupDocs.Viewer, Version=19.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=716fcc553a201e56
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/CISPL/APP/DocProDms/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = D:\CISPL\APP\DocProDms\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\docprodmsuat\c5cf6538
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\docprodmsuat\c5cf6538
LOG: AppName = 51d8e465
Calling assembly : DocPro.DMS.WebApp, Version=2022.6.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b47288d74d395c83.
===
WRN: No matching native image found.
LOG: IL assembly loaded from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\docprodmsuat\c5cf6538\51d8e465\assembly\dl3\6b54b840\c6de7e7b_bd8cd801\GroupDocs.Viewer.dll.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to faced the same problem on one of my application too, after a lots of google search I found  out the dll's were getting locked when I transferred the file into the client machine,

please have a look at that
Right click on the dll and go to property in general tab in attributes section please look for a button called locked, click on that and try again